# Doubt on proof of the validity of induction principle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I would like to ask for some clarifications regarding the proof by contradiction of the validity of the induction principle over the set of non-negative integer.

The induction principle states that if:

1. $P(0) $
2. $\forall x$ in the set of non-negatve integers such that x $ > $ 0,  $P(k)\rightarrow P(k+1)$

Then $\forall x P(x)$

The proof should be the following:

1. Suppose that $\forall x P(x)$ is false. Then there is an x in the set of non-negative integers such that P(x) is false.

So the set $S$ being the set of all non-negative integers x for which $P(x)$ is false is  a non-empty set and it is a sub-set of the set of non-negative integers.

But then, for the well-ordering property, $ \exists y$ in $ S$ such that $y$ is the least element of $S$

2. Now, $y$ is also a non negative integer.
   Since $0$ is the least non-negative integer and $ y \neq 0$, then $0<y$
3. Since the set of non-negative integers is well worderd, between $0$ and $y$ where $0<y$, there exists always an element $y-1$ (for 1, it is 0, for 2, it is 1 and so on).

But then there exists and element $y-1$ that is a non-negative integer and that does not belong to $S$, since $y$ is the minimal element of $S$. So we must conclude that $P(y-1)$ is true. This allows us to infer $P(y)$, arriving to a contradiction. Hence, the validity of induction

To me, step 3 seems to have a n intuitive validity, but I do not get why formally it should be correct.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your definition of "non-negative integer" if it does not already incorporate the induction principle as axiom (scheme)?

Comment: Hmm, seems like step 3 is merely saying that if $y$ is a non-negative integer greater than $0$, then $y-1$ is a non-negative integer. And that is certainly correct, wouldn't you say?